# JQUERY DOM: Select Elements Created After Dom Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a project where I need to change the value of all select inputs of a certain class when a function is called.  The problem is some of the select inputs do not exist when the dom is first loaded, they are created dynamically via Javascript.

The function works fine for selecting all the select inputs that exist when the page was loaded, but does not work for any select inputs that were added to the dom dynamically.

I understand event binding with .on but in this particular case I am not trying to key off of an event like click.  I want to get all elements of this class when this function is called.

Here is the code I am using to create the new select elements.

```
var this_cell = document.getElementById('produce_batch_line_td['+x+']');

var new_select = document.createElement("select");

new_select.name = "produce_batch_line["+x+"]";
new_select.id = "produce_batch_line["+x+"]";        
new_select.className = "produce_batch_line["+invoice_number+"]";

this_cell.appendChild(new_select);

var new_option = document.createElement("option");
new_option.text = "test";
new_option.value = "test";  
new_select.add(new_option);
```

Here is the code I am using to select all select elements of this class.

```
function SetDetailValue(invoice_number, obj) {

    $(".produce_batch_line\\["+invoice_number+"\\]").each(function() { 

        this.value = obj.value; 

    });

}
```

How can I get items of this class added to the dom dynamically?

Comment: Prolly going to need to see your html markup to answer this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this link. I have put one that already exist. And when you click add button it creates dynamicly as well. When you Click the set button it finds them with a java query and puts them into a for loop that changes each ones value one by one.

http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=1a446530189d751d0b15ce104a286eee

[Here is the **DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=1a446530189d751d0b15ce104a286eee)

Comment: Thanks for your example, looks like you are doing exactly what I am doing yet my code wasn't working.  For whatever reason it is working now so I'll mark this as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: I used 'find' function which is checking current elements no matter added dynamicly or had already been there when the function was fired. Thats why my code finds them and works. Thank you btw.

Comment: @GüneySaramalı thank you for the demo. Do you think you could inline it in your post using the `<!-- begin snippet: ... >` feature from StackOverflow?