# jQuery do not accept new fields in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create a generator for lucky numbers. I did it with C# and now with JavaScript and jQuery. [You can see this here](https://embed.plnkr.co/wNh6bXKibNCdlj8ra6ST/). When I add new field - JQ do not see it. Just try to click on numbers in "Your field". I have as standard 7 fields and they work fine but when I add new line script do not recognise it like something useful. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: this is not an image. it's jsFiddle-like-site. jsFiddle does not support a lot of features like plunker.

Comment: I belive what you are asking is this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527885/jquery-dom-select-elements-created-after-dom-load/46528483#46528483

Comment: @MaHarderm check answer , and only change one line as describe in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change below js code. [**check this working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SadFDcezPct4VNHLbv92?p=preview)

Your code:

```
$('.spielzahlen').on('click', function() {
    var list = []
    tablereset()
    var item = $(this).text().split(', ')
    item.forEach(function(index) {
        if (index != "")
            list.push(index)
    })
    console.log($(this).text())
    list_temp = list
    $(this).empty()
    $('#temp').val(list)
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
    list.forEach(function(index) {
        var idt = index - 1
        tds[idt].className = 'checked'
    })
    changeLen(list_temp.length)
})
```

Change it with below code , there is only change in initialization other code are same :

```
$(document).on('click','.spielzahlen', function() {
    var list = []
    tablereset()
    var item = $(this).text().split(', ')
    item.forEach(function(index) {
        if (index != "")
            list.push(index)
    })
    console.log($(this).text())
    list_temp = list
    $(this).empty()
    $('#temp').val(list)
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
    list.forEach(function(index) {
        var idt = index - 1
        tds[idt].className = 'checked'
    })
    changeLen(list_temp.length)
})
```