# Manipulate var in jquery by doing find and text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a WYSIWYG editor in my page. I collect the HTML in a callback function. I would like now change the content with jQuery. For that I do a `find()` to select the text I want to replace. Then I want to replace it, but I'm stuck!

```js
$('.save').click(function() {
  var html = $('#edit').editor('get_html');
  console.log(html)
  var ma_societe_OLD = $(html).find('.ma_societe').attr('data');
  var ma_societe = $(html).find('.ma_societe').text();
  if (ma_societe === ma_societe_OLD) {
    $(html).find('.ma_societe').text('dfdsfsdfds');
  }
  console.log(html);
});
```

As you can see, I want to replace the content of the `span` with my own text. But it's not working.

Comment: This question might help you. [JQUERY DOM: Select Elements Created After Dom Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527885/jquery-dom-select-elements-created-after-dom-load/46528483#46528483)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're making amendments to the jQuery object, but you never store those changes anywhere. You either create a new jQuery object containing the original, unchanged `html`, or return the `html` string directly.

Instead, create `$(html)` in a variable, make your changes to it, then work with it as needed. Something like this:

```js
$('.save').click(function() {
  var html = $('#edit').editor('get_html');
  var $html = $(html);
  var $maSociete = $html.find('.ma_societe')   
  if ($maSociete.text() === $maSociete.attr('data')) {
    $maSociete.text('dfdsfsdfds');
  }

  var result = $html[0].outerHTML
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: awesome ! thks a lot

Comment: No problem, glad to help